# How to get/print resolved dependencies group, name and version from Maven using Gradle?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar

Suppose we have a task in Gradle, that prints artifact group, name and version like this:

```
task printDependencies {
project.configurations.each { conf ->
    conf.dependencies.each { dep ->
        println "${dep.group}:${dep.name}:${dep.version}"
        }
    }
}
```

But what I would to do, is to print/get this information not only for declared dependencies, but to all resolved dependencies too. How to do this in Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to define task like this:

```
task printDependencies {    
    project.configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { id->      
        println id
    }
}
```

The line format that will be printed will be like e.g:

```
play-services-ads-16.0.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0)
```

Which contains all needed info (file, group:name:version)